# ng-model for checkbox doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Js I did the init `$scope.checked = false;` and I do the following

```
<input ng-model="checked" type="checkbox"/>
<button ng-show="checked==true">Save</button>
```

But it doesn't work, any idea why?

Comment: there isn't enough code here to know for sure what the problem is, but a cardinal rule of angular that everyone should follow is "Always use a dot in `ng-model`.".  Because `checked` is a javascript primitive (no dot) rather than an object property (object.property), it is easy to overwrite or hide the value due to Prototype Inheritance.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs.  I suspect that the checkbox is inside some other element that has a scope, like `ng-repeat` or `ng-form`.

Comment: Your code alone works fine http://jsfiddle.net/v3raeufv/